# Cannot comment on any stackexchange site

Tags: support

I don't see `comment` button on any of my SE sites! I'm sure I was able to comment some days before. What happened?

I don't see the comment button.

edit. Could this be because I installed https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/commentblocker/ ?

I put stackexchange.com in whitelist.

Comment: Do you see a comment button here?

Comment: @jmort253 i can now see comment button after disabling addon. weird!

Comment: Well, that addon would certainly be suspect. There are no current issues with Stack Exchange itself that would prevent you from adding comments. Depending on how the whitelist works, you may need to use `*.stackexchange.com`. Also keep in mind that not all sites are *on* the stackexchange.com domain, i.e. stackoverflow.com, superuser.com, serverfault.com, askubuntu.com...

Comment: @downvoter, i dont care for meta points but what is there to disagree in this question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question does look a bit silly, written as it is. "I can't comment any more since I installed _commentblocker_, why is that?"

Comment: @MrLister that was an edit added later.

Answer (score 2):

The https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/commentblocker/ was culprit. Disabled it as in its current version right click context menu doesn't show `trust this site` button, despite what their help page says.